# Question on the adjoint of a function

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

- **1)** Let $E$ a vector space of finite dimension with scalar product $\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>$. We defined the adjoint of $f:E\to E$ the function $g$ defined as $$\left<f(x),y\right>=\left<x,g(y)\right>.$$

Let $S$ s.t. $\left<x,y\right>=x^TSy$. Let $F$ the matrix of $f$ and $G$ the matrix of $g$. If $S=I$, then 
$$\left<Fx,y\right>=x^TF^Ty=\left<x,F^Ty\right>$$
and thus $G=F^T$. But if $S\neq I$, we have $$\left<Fx,y\right>=x^T F^T S y,$$
and how to get $G$ s.t. $\left<x,Gy\right>=\left<Fx,y\right>$ ?

- **2)** We define in a more general way, the adjoint of $f\in L(E,F)$ as $g\in L(F^*,E^*)$ s.t. $g=f\circ u$. What is the link between the adjoint defined in **1)** and the adjoint defined in **2)** ?

Comment: Instead of `<` and `>` it is better to use `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Please post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A change of basis is not necessary, just take $G = S^{-1} F^T S$:
$$\langle Fx,y\rangle = x^TF^TSy = x^TSS^{-1}F^TSy = \langle x,S^{-1}F^TSy\rangle.$$

Answer (score 1):

**1)** There is a basis s.t. $S$ is congruent to $I$ (i.e. there is a matrix $P$ invertible s.t. $S=P^TP$. Let denote $A=P^{-1}FP$ the matrix of $f$ in the new basis.

Then $$\langle APx,Py\rangle= x^TP^TA^TPy=\langle Px,A^TPy\rangle,$$
and thus $F^T$ is the matrix of $g$ in the new basis. 
$$F=PAP^{-1}\quad \text{and}\quad G=PA^TP^{-1}.$$

**2)** You have that $$\left\langle u(x),f\right\rangle_{F,F^*}=\left\langle x,u^T(f)\right\rangle_{E,E^*}.$$

Comment: As said above, @Surb, please use `$\langle$` and `$\rangle$` for $\langle$ and $\rangle$, respectively, instead of $<$ and $>$.

Comment: There's no comma in $\langle x^TP^TF^TPy\rangle$.